@react-pdf/renderer how to build for node when using renderToStream
I am trying to build (bundle) an app that uses @react-pdf/renderer with vite. Then that bundle will be used in different node express app (like a library).
I export some functions that can be used in node, like:
export const getPdf = () => renderToStream(<SomePdf />)

renderToStream is from @react-pdf/renderer. After the build I can import getPdf from the bundle and call it in node. Then it throws this error:

Error: renderToStream is a Node specific API. You're either using this
method in a browser, or your bundler is not loading react-pdf from the
appropriate web build.

I am not calling renderToStream in the browser, but in node.
I want the bundle to contain all the code it needs, including react-pdf/renderer, without imports. Except maybe if needs some node specific stuff like path, fs... in order to call renderToStream
This is my vite config:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import {resolve} from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/generatePdf.tsx'),
      name: 'GeneratePDF',
      fileName: (format) => `generatePDF.${format}.js`,
      formats: ['cjs'],
    },
    target: 'node16',
    outDir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
});

I tried different build configs, like this, but can't make it work.
rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        nodeResolve({
          browser: false,         
          preferBuiltins: true, 
        }),
        commonjs(),            
      ],
      external: ['path', 'fs'],   
    },

If I use renderToStream directly imported from node_modules in node app and get the pdf content from the bundle, then it works. But I don't feel that it is the correct way, I have to keep sync the versions of the pdf library in node with the pdf library in the bundle. I want the node server to not know about react-pdf/renderer at all. It should just use what the bundle gives it.
